# for loop alternative in scala? (Improve performance)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i'm new to scala ,my requirement is delete the particular column records from almost 100 tables,so that i read the data from csv (which is my source) ,selected that particular column and changed into List.

```
val csvDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("inferSchema", true).option("escape", "\"").option("multiline", "true").option("quotes", "").load(inputPath)
    val badrecods = csvDF.select("corrput_id").collect().map(_ (0)).toList
```

then read the metadata from postgres schema, there will get the all the tables list ,here i write the two for loops which is working fine,but performance wat too bad,how can i imporve this

```
  val query = "(select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = '" + db + "' and table_name not in " + excludetables + ") temp "
        val tablesdf = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, table = query, connectionProperties)
        val tablelist = tablesdf.select($"corrput_id").collect().map(_(0)).toList
        println(tablelist)

for (i <- tablelist) {
          val s2 = dbconnection.createStatement()
          for (j <- bad_records) {
            s2.execute("delete from " + db + "." + i + " where corrput_id = '" + j + "' ")
          }
          s2.close()
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to improve your performance, in my opinion, I think you should consider more on optimizing your queries instead! executing a query per row in a table WILL affect your performance, something like

```scala
" where corrput_id IN " + bad_records.map(str => s" '$str' ").mkString("(", ",", ")")
```

would be better. The second point, why don't you just use spark APIs? I mean like using `collect` on a DF and then processing it in a single thread is kind of like awaiting a Future (I mean you are not using the actual power that you can), spark is made to do such things, and can do these efficiently I believe.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I can understand the first one ,what you  explained its perfectly fine, but your saying something spark api's can you please elaborate it, sorry i' m newbie.

Comment: "sorry, i'm newbie", there is nothing to be sorry about :D. Sure, spark sql has some APIs that you can use to create your queries, instead of creating raw queries like `"delet from " + db + ...`. Raw querying is very hard to maintain.

Comment: where clause in supports max values only 1000 in postgres

Comment: @wamshikrishna sure, good point! but the fact still exists that you can group them into batches of 1000 elements and then perform much less queries.

Comment: hi AminMal, one question im updating all these records using where in clause in a single shot in other table ,currently im doing using update query after connection estalish to db in spark .but it takes 14 hours approx for single table records 600k. how we can imporve this

Comment: @wamshikrishna Hi, just to answer your question, I think db design matters a lot in this case, mostly indexes on your columns, so your latest comment exceeds the order of this question in stackoverflow, there are better platforms than this, like [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com). Where you can put your query and some information about your db and table, and you will get better helps! And also, it's generally better to ask a new question in this cases, you will get more noticed.